# Importing WSDL with type that is sometimes nillable

Tags: delphi, soap, wsdl, delphi-xe2

I'm importing an WSDL made for a 3rd party company. This WSDL contains something like

```
<elem a type="typeFoo" nillable = "false">
```

Where typeFoo is an alias for a string .But sometimes contains

```
<elem b type="typeFoo" nillable = "true">
```

So when I'm importing this specific WSDL I realized that Delphi use TXSString if all the elements are nillable = True what I consider a correct behaviour.

But if there is some of them nillable and others not nillable the importer use a simple String(mandatory in the request) for the element. This is a problem because the message expected from the 3rd company needs a nil value but Delphi force me to send something not nil.

Any idea about how to force to use TXS wrapper elements if any of the elements that needs is nillable?

PS: Modifying the content of the imported WSDL code works obviously, I'm looking for an automatic solution for the import process

Comment: Have you checked both `Process nillable and optional elements` and `Use TXSString for simple nillable types` options when importing the WSDL?

Comment: I guess that because of this the importer uses TXSStrings sometimes, otherwise the importer uses just strings.

Comment: What do you mean with "Delphi obeys me to send something not nil." and with "if any of the elements that needs is nillable"? Could you enhance your formulations please?